# GMMGeoTileImageData error with MapKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mapkit

In my viewcontroller I use Maps and I load a list of pins.
When I move the map or zoom in or out it, my app crashes and displays this error:

```
[GMMGeoTileImageData isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x862d3b0
```

This is my code of the view controller:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        statoAnn = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"false"];

        //bottone annulla per tornare indietro
        UIBarButtonItem *annullaButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Annulla" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backView)] autorelease];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = annullaButton;


        //inizializzo la mappa
        mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416)];
        mapView.delegate = self;
        mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
        [self.view addSubview:mapView];

        [self setGmaps:arrData];

        [super viewDidLoad];
    }


/** inizializzo l'annotation del poi mappa **/
- (void) setGmaps:(NSMutableArray*)inputData { 

    // setto la lat e lng 
    CLLocationDegrees latitude;
    CLLocationDegrees longitude;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D poiLocation;
    arrAnn = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i=0; i<[inputData count]; i++) {

        //ricavo la lat e lng del pin
        latitude  = [[[inputData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitude"]  doubleValue];
        longitude = [[[inputData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];

        // setto la location del poi
        poiLocation.latitude = latitude;
        poiLocation.longitude = longitude;
        //[[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude] autorelease];

        //setto il pin
        Annotation *ann = [[Annotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:poiLocation];
        ann.title = [[inputData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"label"];
        [arrAnn addObject:ann];
        [ann release]; 

    }


    if (nil != self.arrAnn) {

        [self.mapView addAnnotations:arrAnn];
        //self.ann = nil;
        self.arrAnn = nil;
    }

}

/** setto il pin nella mappa ***/
- (void)setCurrentLocation:(CLLocation *)location {

    MKCoordinateRegion region = {{0.0f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}};

    region.center = location.coordinate;

    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta  = 0.1f;

    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
}


- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapViewTemp viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    MKPinAnnotationView *view = nil; // return nil for the current user location

        view = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];

        if (nil == view) {
            view = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"] autorelease];
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        }

        [view setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorPurple];
        [view setCanShowCallout:YES];
        [view setAnimatesDrop:YES];

    if (![statoAnn isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
        CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:annotation.coordinate.latitude
                                                          longitude:annotation.coordinate.longitude];
        [self setCurrentLocation:location];
        statoAnn = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"true"];
    } 


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `viewForAnnotation`, this line:

```
statoAnn = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"true"];
```

sets `statoAnn` to an autoreleased string.

When the method exits, `release` is called on `statoAnn` and it no longer owns the memory it was pointing to.  When the method is called again when you zoom or move the map, the memory that `statoAnn` was pointing to is now used by something else (`GMMGeoTileImageData` in this case).  That object is not an `NSString` and doesn't have an `isEqualToString:` method and you get the error you are seeing.

To fix this, set `statoAnn` so the value is retained like you are doing in `viewDidLoad`.  For example, you could change it to:

```
statoAnn = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"true"];
```

You could also declare `statoAnn` as a property (`@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *statoAnn`) and just set it using `self.statoAnn = @"true";`.  The property setter will do the retaining for you.

However, you don't need to use a string to hold a "true" and "false" value.  It's much easier and efficient to use a plain `BOOL` and you won't have to worry about retain/release since it's a primitive type and not an object.

The other thing is that `viewForAnnotation` is not the right place to be setting the map view's `region` in the first place.  You can do that in `viewDidLoad` after the annotations are added.

Another thing: At the top of `viewForAnnotation`, you have the comment "return nil for the current user location" but that code doesn't do that.  It just initializes the view to `nil`.  To actually do what the comment says, you need this:

```
MKPinAnnotationView *view = nil; 

// return nil for the current user location...
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;
```

Finally, if the `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` does return a view (if view != nil), you need to set `view.annotation` to the current annotation since the re-used view may have been for a different annotation.